# Как сделать переключатель между вкладками?

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyside2, qradiobutton

Я решил попробовать создать переключатель между вкладками. Работающий как на картинке ниже

[image: exsample]

Я использовал для этого вот этот код

```
import sys
import random
#from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets           # <--- PySide2
#from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets             # <--- PyQt5

class CollapsibleBox_radio(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, title="", parent=None):
        super(CollapsibleBox_radio, self).__init__(parent)

        self.__expand = False # but on/off
        
        self.toggle_button = QtWidgets.QToolButton(
            text=title, checkable=True, checked=False
        )
        
        def my_fun(self, val):
            self.toggle_button = val
        
        self.toggle_button.setStyleSheet("QToolButton { border: ; }")
        self.toggle_button.setToolButtonStyle(
            QtCore.Qt.ToolButtonTextBesideIcon
        )
        self.toggle_button.setArrowType(QtCore.Qt.RightArrow)
        self.toggle_button.pressed.connect(self.on_pressed)
        self.toggle_animation = QtCore.QParallelAnimationGroup(self)
        self.content_area = QtWidgets.QScrollArea(
            maximumHeight=0, minimumHeight=0
        )
        self.content_area.setSizePolicy(
            QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed
        )
        self.content_area.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)
        
        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.toggle_button.setObjectName(u"click_me")
        
        lay.setSpacing(0)
        lay.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        lay.addWidget(self.toggle_button)
        lay.addWidget(self.content_area)

        self.toggle_animation.addAnimation(
            QtCore.QPropertyAnimation(self, b"minimumHeight")
        )
        self.toggle_animation.addAnimation(
            QtCore.QPropertyAnimation(self, b"maximumHeight")
        )
        self.toggle_animation.addAnimation(
            QtCore.QPropertyAnimation(self.content_area, b"maximumHeight")
        )
        
    #@QtCore.Slot()                                                     # <--- PySide2
    #@QtCore.pyqtSlot()                                                 # <--- PyQt5
    def on_pressed(self):
        self.toggle_button.setArrowType(
            QtCore.Qt.DownArrow if not self.__expand else QtCore.Qt.RightArrow
        )
        self.toggle_animation.setDirection(
            QtCore.QAbstractAnimation.Forward
            if not self.__expand
            else QtCore.QAbstractAnimation.Backward
        )
        # invert vulve __expand
        self.__expand = not self.__expand

        self.toggle_animation.start()

    def setContentLayout(self, layout):
        lay = self.content_area.layout()
        del lay
        self.content_area.setLayout(layout)
        collapsed_height = (
            self.sizeHint().height() - self.content_area.maximumHeight()
        )
        content_height = layout.sizeHint().height()
        for i in range(self.toggle_animation.animationCount()):
            animation = self.toggle_animation.animationAt(i)
            animation.setDuration(500)
            animation.setStartValue(collapsed_height)
            animation.setEndValue(collapsed_height + content_height)

        content_animation = self.toggle_animation.animationAt(
            self.toggle_animation.animationCount() - 1
        )
        content_animation.setDuration(500)
        content_animation.setStartValue(0)
        content_animation.setEndValue(content_height)

        
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        #------centralwidget------
        centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget() 
        centralwidget.setObjectName(u"centralwidget")
        self.setCentralWidget(centralwidget)
        #------layout------
        central_w_layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(centralwidget)
        central_w_layout.setObjectName(u"central_w_layout")
        #------Spacer------
        vs_up = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(17, 105, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        central_w_layout.addItem(vs_up, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        hs_left = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(327, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        central_w_layout.addItem(hs_left, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        hs_right = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(326, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        central_w_layout.addItem(hs_right, 1, 2, 1, 1)
        vs_down = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(20, 105, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        central_w_layout.addItem(vs_down, 2, 1, 1, 1)
        #------block------
        block = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        block.setObjectName(u"block")
        central_w_layout.addWidget(block, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        #------layout------
        vlay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(block)  
        vlay.setObjectName(u"central_c_layout")
        #Radio
        test1_menu_block = QtWidgets.QWidget(block)
        test1_menu_block.setObjectName(u"test1_menu_block")
        verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(test1_menu_block)
        verticalLayout.setObjectName(u"verticalLayout")
        #add
        vlay.addWidget(test1_menu_block)
        #----Logic_but----
        for x in range(3):
            #test1_but_menu = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(test1_menu_block, clicked=lambda _, check_1 = test1_but_menu.isChecked(): if check_1 == True: print('check') else: print('uncheked'))
            test1_but_menu = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(test1_menu_block, checkable=True, checked=False)
            test1_but_menu.setObjectName("test1_butt_menu_{}".format(x))
            verticalLayout.addWidget(test1_but_menu)
            def off_pressed_radio():
                check_1 = test1_but_menu.isChecked()
                if check_1 == True:
                    print('check')
                    test1_but_menu.setAutoExclusive(True)   #Unchecked/Checked
                    test1_but_menu.setChecked(False)    #Unchecked/Checked
                    test1_but_menu.setAutoExclusive(False)  #Unchecked/Checked
                else:
                    print('uncheked')
            test1_but_menu.pressed.connect(off_pressed_radio)
            box_rad = CollapsibleBox_radio("manu_radio{}".format(x))
            #box_rad.my_fun(test1_but_menu)
            vlay.addWidget(box_rad)
            lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
            lay.setSpacing(0)
            lay.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
            for j in range(3):
                label = QtWidgets.QLabel("Label {}-{}".format(x, j))
                color = QtGui.QColor(*[random.randint(0, 255) for _ in range(3)])
                label.setStyleSheet(
                    "background-color: {}; color : white;".format(color.name())
                )
                label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
                label.setMaximumWidth(150)
                label.setMinimumHeight(25)
                textButton = "Button {}-{}".format(x, j) 
                pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(textButton, 
                    clicked=lambda _, t=textButton: print(t))
                pushButton.setMaximumWidth(150)
                pushButton.setMinimumHeight(25)
                lay.addWidget(pushButton)
                lay.addWidget(label)
            box_rad.setContentLayout(lay)       
            
        vlay.addStretch()        

StyleSheet = """
#centralwidget QWidget QWidget,
#centralwidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget,
#centralwidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget,
#centralwidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget,
#centralwidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget{
background:#000;
color:#fff;
}
#centralwidget QWidget,
#centralwidget QWidget QWidget QWidget,
#centralwidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget,
#centralwidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget,
#centralwidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget{
background:#fff;
color:#000;
}
#click_me{
background:#000;
color:#fff;
}
"""

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyleSheet(StyleSheet)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.resize(640, 570) #Size window
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Но к сожалению я так и не смог правильно настроить код, чтобы он работал как мне нужно.
Если кому интересно может кто-нибудь мне помочь с этим?

Версия 2

```
import sys
import random
#from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets           # <--- PySide2
#from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets             # <--- PyQt5

class CollapsibleBox_radio(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, title="", parent=None):
        super(CollapsibleBox_radio, self).__init__(parent)

        self._expand = False                                # - self.__expand ; + self._expand  !!!

        self.toggle_button = QtWidgets.QToolButton(
            text=title, checkable=True, checked=False
        )

        self.toggle_button.setStyleSheet("QToolButton { height:0px; width:0px; opacity:0; }")
        self.toggle_button.setToolButtonStyle(
            QtCore.Qt.ToolButtonTextBesideIcon
        )
        self.toggle_button.setArrowType(QtCore.Qt.RightArrow)
        self.toggle_button.pressed.connect(self.on_pressed)
        self.toggle_animation = QtCore.QParallelAnimationGroup(self)
        self.content_area = QtWidgets.QScrollArea(
            maximumHeight=0, minimumHeight=0
        )
        self.content_area.setSizePolicy(
            QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed
        )
        self.content_area.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)

        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.toggle_button.setObjectName(u"click_me")

        lay.setSpacing(0)
        lay.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        lay.addWidget(self.toggle_button)
        lay.addWidget(self.content_area)

        self.toggle_animation.addAnimation(
            QtCore.QPropertyAnimation(self, b"minimumHeight")
        )
        self.toggle_animation.addAnimation(
            QtCore.QPropertyAnimation(self, b"maximumHeight")
        )
        self.toggle_animation.addAnimation(
            QtCore.QPropertyAnimation(self.content_area, b"maximumHeight")
        )

    #@QtCore.Slot()                                                     # <--- PySide2
    #@QtCore.pyqtSlot()                                                 # <--- PyQt5
    def on_pressed(self):
        self.toggle_button.setArrowType(
            QtCore.Qt.DownArrow if not self._expand else QtCore.Qt.RightArrow
        )
        self.toggle_animation.setDirection(
            QtCore.QAbstractAnimation.Forward
            if not self._expand
            else QtCore.QAbstractAnimation.Backward
        )
        # invert vulve _expand
        self._expand = not self._expand

        self.toggle_animation.start()

    def setContentLayout(self, layout):
        lay = self.content_area.layout()
        del lay
        self.content_area.setLayout(layout)
        collapsed_height = (
            self.sizeHint().height() - self.content_area.maximumHeight()
        )
        content_height = layout.sizeHint().height()
        for i in range(self.toggle_animation.animationCount()):
            animation = self.toggle_animation.animationAt(i)
            animation.setDuration(500)
            animation.setStartValue(collapsed_height)
            animation.setEndValue(collapsed_height + content_height)

        content_animation = self.toggle_animation.animationAt(
            self.toggle_animation.animationCount() - 1
        )
        content_animation.setDuration(500)
        content_animation.setStartValue(0)
        content_animation.setEndValue(content_height)


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    # number of radio
    def num(self):
        return 3
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        #------centralwidget------
        centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget() 
        centralwidget.setObjectName(u"centralwidget")
        self.setCentralWidget(centralwidget)
        #------layout------
        central_w_layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(centralwidget)
        central_w_layout.setObjectName(u"central_w_layout")
        #------Spacer------
        vs_up = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(17, 105, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        central_w_layout.addItem(vs_up, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        hs_left = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(327, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        central_w_layout.addItem(hs_left, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        hs_right = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(326, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        central_w_layout.addItem(hs_right, 1, 2, 1, 1)
        vs_down = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(20, 105, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        central_w_layout.addItem(vs_down, 2, 1, 1, 1)
        #------block------
        block = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        block.setObjectName(u"block")
        central_w_layout.addWidget(block, 1, 1, 1, 1)             ######
        #------layout------
        layout_block = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(block)  
        layout_block.setObjectName(u"layout_block")
        #------radio_block------
        radio_block = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        radio_block.setObjectName(u"radio_block")
        layout_block.addWidget(radio_block)             ######
        #------radio_layout------
        radio_layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(radio_block)  
        radio_layout.setObjectName(u"radio_layout")
        #------radio content------
        radio_content = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()   
        radio_content.setObjectName(u"radio_content")
        self.radio_content_arr = []
        #------radio but------
        self.tes_but = []
        for x in range(self.num()):
            tes_but_add = QtWidgets.QRadioButton('{}'.format(x))
            tes_but_add.setObjectName("radio_but_{}".format(x))
            self.tes_but.append(tes_but_add)
            
            self.tes_but[x].pressed.connect(self.offRadioButton)
            self.tes_but[x].toggled.connect(self.onRadioButton)
            #------ADD------
            radio_layout.addWidget(self.tes_but[x])
            #------BOX------
            box_rad = CollapsibleBox_radio("manu_radio{}".format(x))
            self.radio_content_arr.append(box_rad)
            radio_content.addWidget(box_rad)
            lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
            lay.setSpacing(0)
            lay.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
            #------content------
            for j in range(3):
                label = QtWidgets.QLabel("Label {}-{}".format(x, j))
                color = QtGui.QColor(*[random.randint(0, 255) for _ in range(3)])
                label.setStyleSheet(
                    "background-color: {}; color : white;".format(color.name())
                )
                label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
                label.setMaximumWidth(150)
                label.setMinimumHeight(25)
                textButton = "Button {}-{}".format(x, j) 
                pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(textButton, 
                    clicked=lambda _, t=textButton: print(t))
                pushButton.setMaximumWidth(150)
                pushButton.setMinimumHeight(25)
                lay.addWidget(pushButton)
                lay.addWidget(label)
            box_rad.setContentLayout(lay)       
        #------ADD------
        radio_content.addStretch()    
        layout_block.addLayout(radio_content)                        # +++

    def offRadioButton(self):
        check_1 = self.sender().isChecked()
        if check_1 == True:
            print('check')
            self.sender().setAutoExclusive(True)   #Unchecked/Checked
            self.sender().setChecked(False)    #Unchecked/Checked
            self.sender().setAutoExclusive(False)  #Unchecked/Checked
        else:
            print('uncheked')
    
    def onRadioButton(self):
        for r in range(self.num()):
            if self.radio_content_arr[r]._expand:
                self.radio_content_arr[r].toggle_button.click()
            if self.tes_but[r].isChecked() and (not self.radio_content_arr[r]._expand): 
                self.radio_content_arr[r].toggle_button.click()
            elif not self.tes_but[r].isChecked() and self.radio_content_arr[r]._expand:    
                self.radio_content_arr[r].toggle_button.click()                

StyleSheet = """
#centralwidget QWidget QWidget,
#centralwidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget,
#centralwidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget,
#centralwidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget,
#centralwidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget{
background:#000;
color:#fff;
}
#centralwidget QWidget,
#centralwidget QWidget QWidget QWidget,
#centralwidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget,
#centralwidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget,
#centralwidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget{
background:#fff;
color:#000;
}
#click_me{
background:#000;
color:#fff;
}
"""

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyleSheet(StyleSheet)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.resize(640, 570) #Size window
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

В версии 2 я не смог решить следующие проблемы

1 Когда кнопка радио нажата дважды она из радио превращается в checkbox

2 Я не смог полностью скрыть кнопку toggle_button

3 Скрытие и раскрытие меню с контентом происходит одновременно а не постепенно как на картинке в начале вопроса

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

1. `QRadioButton'ы` включены в `QGroupBox`.
2. `CollapsibleBox_radio'ы` добавил в список `list_box_rad`.
3. `self.__expand` заменил на `self._expand`.

---

```
import sys
import random
#from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets           # <--- PySide2
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets             # <--- PyQt5

class CollapsibleBox_radio(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, title="", parent=None):
        super(CollapsibleBox_radio, self).__init__(parent)

        self._expand = False                                # - self.__expand ; + self._expand  !!!

        self.toggle_button = QtWidgets.QToolButton(
            text=title, checkable=True, checked=False
        )

        def my_fun(self, val):
            self.toggle_button = val

        self.toggle_button.setStyleSheet("QToolButton { border: ; }")
        self.toggle_button.setToolButtonStyle(
            QtCore.Qt.ToolButtonTextBesideIcon
        )
        self.toggle_button.setArrowType(QtCore.Qt.RightArrow)
        self.toggle_button.pressed.connect(self.on_pressed)
        self.toggle_animation = QtCore.QParallelAnimationGroup(self)
        self.content_area = QtWidgets.QScrollArea(
            maximumHeight=0, minimumHeight=0
        )
        self.content_area.setSizePolicy(
            QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed
        )
        self.content_area.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)

        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.toggle_button.setObjectName(u"click_me")

        lay.setSpacing(0)
        lay.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        lay.addWidget(self.toggle_button)
        lay.addWidget(self.content_area)

        self.toggle_animation.addAnimation(
            QtCore.QPropertyAnimation(self, b"minimumHeight")
        )
        self.toggle_animation.addAnimation(
            QtCore.QPropertyAnimation(self, b"maximumHeight")
        )
        self.toggle_animation.addAnimation(
            QtCore.QPropertyAnimation(self.content_area, b"maximumHeight")
        )

    #@QtCore.Slot()                                                     # <--- PySide2
    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()                                                 # <--- PyQt5
    def on_pressed(self):
        self.toggle_button.setArrowType(
            QtCore.Qt.DownArrow if not self._expand else QtCore.Qt.RightArrow
        )
        self.toggle_animation.setDirection(
            QtCore.QAbstractAnimation.Forward
            if not self._expand
            else QtCore.QAbstractAnimation.Backward
        )
        # invert vulve _expand
        self._expand = not self._expand

        self.toggle_animation.start()

    def setContentLayout(self, layout):
        lay = self.content_area.layout()
        del lay
        self.content_area.setLayout(layout)
        collapsed_height = (
            self.sizeHint().height() - self.content_area.maximumHeight()
        )
        content_height = layout.sizeHint().height()
        for i in range(self.toggle_animation.animationCount()):
            animation = self.toggle_animation.animationAt(i)
            animation.setDuration(500)
            animation.setStartValue(collapsed_height)
            animation.setEndValue(collapsed_height + content_height)

        content_animation = self.toggle_animation.animationAt(
            self.toggle_animation.animationCount() - 1
        )
        content_animation.setDuration(500)
        content_animation.setStartValue(0)
        content_animation.setEndValue(content_height)


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        #------centralwidget------
        centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget() 
        centralwidget.setObjectName(u"centralwidget")
        self.setCentralWidget(centralwidget)

        #------layout------
        central_w_layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(centralwidget)
        central_w_layout.setObjectName(u"central_w_layout")
        #------Spacer------
        vs_up = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(17, 105, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        central_w_layout.addItem(vs_up, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        hs_left = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(327, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        central_w_layout.addItem(hs_left, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        hs_right = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(326, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        central_w_layout.addItem(hs_right, 1, 2, 1, 1)
        vs_down = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(20, 105, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        central_w_layout.addItem(vs_down, 2, 1, 1, 1)

#+ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
        self.groupbox = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(self)
        layout_H = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.groupbox)
        layout_H.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

        self.radio_0 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton("0")
        self.radio_0.toggled.connect(self.onRadioButton)
        layout_H.addWidget(self.radio_0)
        self.radio_1 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton("1")
        self.radio_1.toggled.connect(self.onRadioButton)
        layout_H.addWidget(self.radio_1)
        self.radio_2 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton("2")
        self.radio_2.toggled.connect(self.onRadioButton)
        layout_H.addWidget(self.radio_2)

        central_w_layout.addWidget(self.groupbox, 1, 1, 1, 1)
#+ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^        

        '''
        #------block------
        block = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        block.setObjectName(u"block")
        central_w_layout.addWidget(block, 1, 1, 1, 5)             ######

        #------layout------
        vlay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(block)  
        vlay.setObjectName(u"central_c_layout")
        #Radio
        test1_menu_block = QtWidgets.QWidget(block)
        test1_menu_block.setObjectName(u"test1_menu_block")
        verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(test1_menu_block)
        verticalLayout.setObjectName(u"verticalLayout")
        #add
        vlay.addWidget(test1_menu_block)
        #----Logic_but----
        for x in range(3):
            #test1_but_menu = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(test1_menu_block, clicked=lambda _, check_1 = test1_but_menu.isChecked(): if check_1 == True: print('check') else: print('uncheked'))
            test1_but_menu = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(test1_menu_block, checkable=True, checked=False)
            test1_but_menu.setObjectName("test1_butt_menu_{}".format(x))
            verticalLayout.addWidget(test1_but_menu)
            def off_pressed_radio():
                check_1 = test1_but_menu.isChecked()
                if check_1 == True:
                    print('check')
                    test1_but_menu.setAutoExclusive(True)   #Unchecked/Checked
                    test1_but_menu.setChecked(False)    #Unchecked/Checked
                    test1_but_menu.setAutoExclusive(False)  #Unchecked/Checked
                else:
                    print('uncheked')
            test1_but_menu.pressed.connect(off_pressed_radio)
        '''   

#+ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv            
        vlay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()   
        vlay.setObjectName(u"central_c_layout")
        self.list_box_rad = []                                              # +++ !!!

        for x in range(3):    
#+ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

            box_rad = CollapsibleBox_radio("manu_radio{}".format(x))
            #box_rad.my_fun(test1_but_menu)

            self.list_box_rad.append(box_rad)                                # +++

            vlay.addWidget(box_rad)
            lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
            lay.setSpacing(0)
            lay.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
            for j in range(3):
                label = QtWidgets.QLabel("Label {}-{}".format(x, j))
                color = QtGui.QColor(*[random.randint(0, 255) for _ in range(3)])
                label.setStyleSheet(
                    "background-color: {}; color : white;".format(color.name())
                )
                label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
                label.setMaximumWidth(150)
                label.setMinimumHeight(25)
                textButton = "Button {}-{}".format(x, j) 
                pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(textButton, 
                    clicked=lambda _, t=textButton: print(t))
                pushButton.setMaximumWidth(150)
                pushButton.setMinimumHeight(25)
                lay.addWidget(pushButton)
                lay.addWidget(label)
            box_rad.setContentLayout(lay)       

        vlay.addStretch()    

        central_w_layout.addLayout(vlay, 2, 1, 1, 1)                        # +++

#+ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
    def onRadioButton(self):
        if self.sender().text() == '0':
            if self.radio_0.isChecked() and (not self.list_box_rad[0]._expand): 
                self.list_box_rad[0].toggle_button.click()
            elif not self.radio_0.isChecked() and self.list_box_rad[0]._expand:    
                self.list_box_rad[0].toggle_button.click()                
            if self.list_box_rad[1]._expand:
                self.list_box_rad[1].toggle_button.click()
            if self.list_box_rad[2]._expand:
                self.list_box_rad[2].toggle_button.click()
        if self.sender().text() == '1':
            if self.radio_1.isChecked() and (not self.list_box_rad[1]._expand): 
                self.list_box_rad[1].toggle_button.click()
            elif not self.radio_1.isChecked() and self.list_box_rad[1]._expand:    
                self.list_box_rad[1].toggle_button.click()  
            if self.list_box_rad[0]._expand:
                self.list_box_rad[0].toggle_button.click()
            if self.list_box_rad[2]._expand:
                self.list_box_rad[2].toggle_button.click()                
        if self.sender().text() == '2':
            if self.radio_2.isChecked() and (not self.list_box_rad[2]._expand): 
                self.list_box_rad[2].toggle_button.click()
            elif not self.radio_2.isChecked() and self.list_box_rad[2]._expand:    
                self.list_box_rad[2].toggle_button.click()  
            if self.list_box_rad[0]._expand:
                self.list_box_rad[0].toggle_button.click()
            if self.list_box_rad[1]._expand:
                self.list_box_rad[1].toggle_button.click() 
#+ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

StyleSheet = """
#centralwidget QWidget QWidget,
#centralwidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget,
#centralwidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget,
#centralwidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget,
#centralwidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget{
background:#000;
color:#fff;
}
#centralwidget QWidget,
#centralwidget QWidget QWidget QWidget,
#centralwidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget,
#centralwidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget,
#centralwidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget{
background:#fff;
color:#000;
}
#click_me{
background:#000;
color:#fff;
}
"""

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyleSheet(StyleSheet)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.resize(640, 570) #Size window
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо большое ваш код помог мне понять что можно использовать массивы как динамическую переменную а функцию с self как способ из одной функции перенести информацию в другую но это так и не решило мой вопрос. Код вопроса я обновил.